# With D3, how can I set attribute ("fill", "none") of axis path and line, but not text (without editing stylesheet)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I do this, the axis text's fill is also set to none.

```
     graph.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .call(rrd3.xAxis);
```

How can I set fill to none for the path and the line, but not the text. I want to do this with javascript through d3. I can get it working by editing my stylesheet but that's not how I want to do it.

Comment: Move the code the to where you create paths and lines. As  it stands all child elements of that `<g>` will inherit the respective properties.

Comment: That was my first thought but I never actually create the path and lines. I create the axis which seems to have all those things built in.

Comment: The cleanest approach would be to use stylesheets. Without them, no easy/clean way comes to my mind.

Comment: Maybe that is the only way. For now, I'll keep it in my stylesheet but I'll leave this question open in case someone can think of a way.

Comment: There are ways ... you could select any path and line element below the appended `<g>` and apply the styles to those, but that's far from clean ...

Comment: how do i do that if those elements dont have class names as an attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the elements you want to change explicitly:

```
var axG = graph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(rrd3.xAxis);
axG.selectAll("path").attr("fill", "none");
axG.selectAll("line").attr("fill", "none");
```